# Lookup Field to ALSO include choice field

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a field called "Client" and a field called "InsuranceCompany" is a custom list. The "InsuranceCompany" field is a Drop-Down Choice field. In another custom list I am performing a lookup against "Client" field in my first list, however I want to include the "InsuranceCompany" so it is displayed as well.

Is this possible?

I am using O365/SharePoint Online

Answer (score 2):

No, choice columns can not be pulled over as an additional column when setting a lookup column. Your option would be in this case to create a workflow that fires on item creation/change to look up the InsuranceCompany field and set a field in your list to that value.

Another alternative would be to convert your choice column to a single line of text, then it could be used in that fashion. You would then have to put some validation rules in place or come up with a JavaScript/jQuery solution to enforce data integrity so you don't get things like State Farm or Statefarm or statfarm.